# How do you inherit the attributes of multiple classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, composition

## Problem:

i'm building a program that required being able to have the same attributes to multiple classes. those attributes have to be stored somewhere for classes to use for their instances.

let's say we have 2 classes:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
```

i want to create a third class that contains the attributes `a` and `b` from both `A` and `B` respectively. how do you do so?

## Attempts:

composition doesn't work because i'd have to redeclare the name like this which is error-prone once i end up mistyping a letter:

```py
class C():
    def __init__(self, a: A, b: B):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

that's also a mess when you have to access values, like `C().a.a` is unclean, but i'm expecting more of `C().a`

inheritance with `super()` doesn't work either:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        super().__init__() # no way to pass the variable "b"

class B():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        super().__init__() # no way to pass the variable "a"

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(???) # no way to pass the variables to each specific class
```

Comment: *inheritance with super() doesn't work either* - none of your examples actually use inheritance?

Comment: added the class in question, sorry for that inconvenience

Comment: A little bit of context would be useful.. but you can also directly do something like: `A.__init__(self, a)` inside the `__init__` of `C`

Comment: added context. for doing `A.__init__`, i think it could work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass value to instance A() or B(), but is class accepted.

```
class A:
    a = 'aa'


class B:
    b = 'bb'


class C:
    def __init__(self, a: A = A(), b: B = B()):
        self.a = a.a
        self.b = b.b


print(C().a)
# aa
```

Comment: has the same problems as composition, sorry